# .net 5.0 hotchocolate graphql server version 11 where is schema stiching?

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

Trying to follow along [Hotchocolate ChilliCream blog](https://chillicream.com/blog/2019/02/20/schema-stitching)

Basic GraphQl server runs OK. However, when I add schema stiching as instructed in the blog, couldn't build the project. My package references as below;

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="GraphQL.Server.Ui.Voyager" Version="4.4.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Abstractions" Version="11.0.9" />
      <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore" Version="11.0.9" />
      <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Data.EntityFramework" Version="11.0.9" />
      <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.Stitching" Version="11.0.9" />
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="5.0.3">
          <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
          <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="5.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

and try to add

```
      services.AddStitchedSchema(builder => builder
              .AddSchemaFromHttp("messages")
              .AddSchemaFromHttp("users")
              .AddSchemaFromHttp("analytics"));
```

below build error happens;

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'IServiceCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddStitchedSchema' and no accessible extension method 'AddStitchedSchema' accepting a first argument of type 'IServiceCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  GraphQL.WebApi  C:\github\.net5.0_graphql_hotchocolate\GraphQL.WebApi\Startup.cs    46  Active
```

How to add schema stiching in this project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The schema builders have been combined to a single one.

You can just do

```cs
 services
     .AddGraphQLServer()
     .AddRemoteSchema("messages")
     .AddRemoteSchema("users")
```

This PR is the WIP docs:
https://github.com/ChilliCream/hotchocolate/pull/2780